# SignalR Client Page Disconnects After Random Amount of Time Elapses

Tags: signalr

I have an administrative "monitoring" page that connects to my SignalR hub and just listens for all SignalR broadcast messages, displaying a realtime list of activity from the server.  However, often after an arbitrary and variable duration of elapsed time, it ceases to hear any more messages from the server.

I had believed that SignalR connections were self-repairing.  Is it reasonable for me to think that I should be able to leave a page open indefinitely and have it still retain its live connection to the server, continuing to hear events?  How does one troubleshoot this sort of thing?

Comment: You are correct the connections are self repairing.  What client are you using?  What type of hosting are you using?  What are the logs on the client?  See my answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003655/client-constantly-reconnecting for how to setup logging.

Comment: What version of SignalR are you using? You can look at the network tab in your browser's F12 tools to see what requests are being made and what responses are being received.

Comment: $.connection.hub.logging = true

Comment: Thanks, guys, I forgot about logging, that will probably yield some clues!

Comment: Interesting.  It works for a while (and receives notifications often for minutes on end), but then I see this in the logs:

SignalR: An error occurred using longPolling. Status = error...
McAfee Web Gateway - Notification
...
Error Message: (20100) The connection downloading the file was terminated.
...
SignalR: Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout (40000ms), disconnecting.

At my work, Internet is accessed via McAfee Web Gateway.  Can SignalR support these scenarios?