# SignalR client keeps reconnecting after request timeout

Tags: c#, signalr

I am using latest SignalR version 2.3.0 with C# client.
The problem I am facing is kind of mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003655/client-constantly-reconnecting) on stackoverflow. But that issue is few years old and it is already closed on github.

The issue I am facing is that whenever a request timeout from client to server then client starts reconnecting to server and then keeps on reconnecting. I tried defining the WebSocket protocol also in connection but result is still same.

```
 _connection.Start(new Transports.WebSocketTransport()).Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

I am looking for a persistent connection between server and client.

I have added an event handler on StateChanged event to capture the state changes of SignalR client.

Here's the screenshot of reconnecting state

[image]

Does anybody have any idea why it's happening and how it can be prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason might be because your `OnReconnect` even doesn't fire and then again your `OnDisconnected` doesn't fire when the client calls the `stop method as described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/blob/master/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events.md):

> If the client goes into reconnecting mode but can't establish a
>   transport connection within the disconnect timeout limit, the server
>   terminates the SignalR connection. When that happens, the server
>   executes the Hub's OnDisconnected method and queues up a disconnect
>   message to send to the client in case the client manages to connect
>   later. If the client then does reconnect, it receives the disconnect
>   command and calls the Stop method. In this scenario, OnReconnected is
>   not executed when the client reconnects, and OnDisconnected is not
>   executed when the client calls Stop.

*This is referring to SignalR version 2, But I believe that it will of help to you as well.*

Worth mention as well, **that you will contentiously try to reconnect if you call `start` from your `closed` event (or `disconnect` in JavaScript`)** as said:

> In some applications you might want to automatically re-establish a
>   connection after it has been lost and the attempt to reconnect has
>   timed out. To do that, you can call the Start method from your Closed
>   event handler (disconnected event handler on JavaScript clients). You
>   might want to wait a period of time before calling Start in order to
>   avoid doing this too frequently when the server or the physical
>   connection are unavailable. The following code sample is for a
>   JavaScript client using the generated proxy.

anyway, the simplest way to disconnect your client from the server up until version 2 is to implement the `disconnect` method on the client an call it from the server as mentioned:

> SignalR version 2 does not have a built-in server API for
>   disconnecting clients. There are plans for adding this functionality
>   in the future. In the current SignalR release, the simplest way to
>   disconnect a client from the server is to implement a disconnect
>   method on the client and call that method from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You have pointed me to the right direction. I have checked the OnReconnected() event and found that I have written some code before base.OnReconnected() event which is causing exception. The code lines causing issue is HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]; This is working fine OnConnected() and OnReconnected normally but throwing null reference on reconnection after request timeout. Any idea about this?

Comment: try calling the start method from your closed event handler as mentioned in the article, it might do the magic.

Comment: The problem is on Reconnecting event before closed. Now when I know the issue I can use workaround and pass the server url in header instead of using HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]; Thanks for your help and will definitely mark it as answer after finishing my implementation.